# Mac Unity package manager error resolving packages: one or more packages could not be added to local file system

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use unity 2021.3.7f1, I was creating a new game on unity hub when i got this error message:
[one or more packages could not be added to local file system com.unity.collab-proxy: ENOENT no such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTnk3.png)

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue today with 2 packages:**

- Timeline 1.6.x
- Testframework 1.1.x

**To fix that:**

- (Testframework)I went to package manager under the window tab in unity, and searched for the missed packages, I found out that the Testframework package was outdated, so I update it and had its error gone, now I'm left with timeline framework that I found updated.
- (Timeline)I went to the folder of another project that works fine and uses an older unity editor version 2020.3.18,  Packages -> manifest.json . Copied its version of Timeline which is     "com.unity.timeline": "1.4.8", and Past it on the manifest.json of my project and Tada everythings works fine now .

*HOPE IT HELPED*